# Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home' After creating MVC Forum

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to create the mvc forum in web application project. 
after I install the package, I always getting this error, I'm also trying to put this solution

```
   context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_default",
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "AppName.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
);
```

Into the controller but I can not find the controller location

```
mvcForum.Web.Areas.Forum.Controllers.HomeController
mvcForum.Web.Areas.ForumAdmin.Controllers.HomeController
```

I'm trying to put this

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "GroupAssignment.Controllers" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "forum",
              url: "mvcForum/Web/Areas/Forum/Controller/{action}/{id}",
              defaults: new
              {
                  controller = "mvcForum/Web/Areas/Forum/Controller/",
                  action = "Index",
                  issueId = UrlParameter.Optional,
                  projectId = UrlParameter.Optional
              }
          );

            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "forumadmin",
              url: "mvcForum/Web/Areas/ForumAdmin/Controller/{action}/{id}",
              defaults: new
              {
                  controller = "mvcForum/Web/Areas/ForumAdmin/Controller",
                  action = "Index",
                  issueId = UrlParameter.Optional,
                  projectId = UrlParameter.Optional
              }
          );

        }
```

To my  **Global.asax.cs**
But still no work for me

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one can answer it so I find by myself for few hour.

Actually I only need to modify the RegisterRoutes not on Global.asax.cs is in RouteConfig.cs